# Printing statements 1000 times in C

Tags: c

I'm really new to C and programming in general and I would like some help to review what I did.

```
  #include<stdio.h>

void helloWorld();

int main(void) {

    helloWorld();

    return 0;
}

void helloWorld() { 
    int (i =1; i <= 1000; i++);
    printf("Hello World."); // I want to print the statement here 1000 times
}
```

It seems that I'm lost, I tried the `int (i =1; i <= 1000; i++);` but I'm not sure if it's the correct method because only one statement is printed out.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What does it mean to have ```int (i =1; i <= 1000; i++)```?

Comment: Besides, this code does not even compile. Paste the actual code.

Comment: Get yourself a book that explains loops.

`int (i =1; i <= 1000; i++);` is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted doesn't even compile, so it doesn't even produce an executable, much less one that produces one line of output as you claim.

But if instead of

```c
int (i =1; i <= 1000; i++);
```

you had

```c
for (int i =1; i <= 1000; i++);
```

then you would see the the result you describe. Because that loop is equivalent to

```c
for (int i =1; i <= 1000; i++) { }
```

You want

```c
for (int i =1; i <= 1000; i++)   // No semi-colon
   printf("Hello World.");
```

or

```c
for (int i =1; i <= 1000; i++) {
   printf("Hello World.");
}
```

Comment: I see, I overlooked the semi-colon. Thank you so much for the help.